# Is Relativistic GAN better than WGAN-GP?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, wasserstein-gan, image-super-resolution

I am currently reading the ESRGAN paper and I noticed that they have used Relativistic GAN for training discriminator. So, is it because Relativistic GAN leads to better results than WGAN-GP?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for answer, as explained in Paper: [The relativistic discriminator: a key element missing from standard GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00734)!,

Yes,  Standard RaGAN with gradient penalty generate data of better quality than WGAN-GP while only requiring a single discriminator update per generator update (reducing the time taken for reaching the state-of-the-art by 400%).The  images generated by RaGAN are of significantly better quality than the ones generated by WGAN-GP and SGAN with spectral normalization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the two **Generative Adversarial Network (GAN)** models – **Relativistic GAN** and **WGAN-GP** – each have their own advantages and disadvantages. However, some experts believe that, overall, Relativistic GAN may be slightly better than WGAN-GP, due to its improved **stability** and **performance** on a variety of tasks.

One reason why Relativistic GAN may be slightly better than WGAN-GP is that it is generally more **stable**, meaning it is less likely to produce artifacts or results that are significantly different from the real data. Additionally, **Relativistic GAN** has shown better results on a variety of tasks, including **image generation**, **object detection**, and **image super-resolutio**n.